# The alignment of text within a list with LESS and layers optimization

Tags: html, css

I need your professional help with my code!
I'm started learn web-development, and now I have a trouble with my project.

I don't understand how to work with layers on web page. If I want make adaptive site, my layers is overlap during resize browser window. How to make my Pin more adaptive in due form?

And how alignment objects inside in list on menu (in my code -> div-user;circle with numbers)([LINK TO PIN](https://codepen.io/Madd09/pen/jAJmpk))?

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

@green: #2ECC71;
@white: #E4F1FE;

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: @green;
}

.user {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  .name {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    color: @white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    left: 10px;
    align-items: center;
  }
  li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    justify-content: center; 
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    background-color: darken(@green, 2%);
  }
}

.avatar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  margin: 0;
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: darken(@green, 2%);
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    color: @white;
    &:hover {
      background-color: lighten(@green, 10%);
      border-bottom: 2px solid lighten(@green, 25%);
    }
    &:active {
      border-bottom: 2px solid lighten(@green, 25%);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="user">
        <img class="avatar"
             src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/">
        <p class="user name">UserName</p>
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should absolutely look into learning grid systems and how to think of your site in terms of stackable "blocks" containing stuff, rather than a bunch of individual items you need to shuffle around the page at different screen sizes!

So instead of seeing the image, list and buttons as things you should statically make, see them as groups of content which you would then stack on mobile devices, like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/losIB.jpg

I'd definitely agree with lwozniak that learning and utilising one of the many responsive front-end frameworks will give you a good structure to practise and learn grid systems in!

You have a choice of frameworks to utilise (we personally use UIKit, but you should use whatever you feel is best for you, majority use Bootstrap!):

- Bootstrap
- UIKit
- Foundation

Comment: Thank for your opinion! I try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn Bootstrap Grid System:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
It'll help you!